# How to Restrict some special character in password field

Tags: 8, theming, users, configuration

I'm very new in Drupal, I would like to restrict some special characters from user password field Is there any way to edit configuration of core modules 
i'm trying to create preg_match modules .
i would like to allow only these character in password fields.

```
preg_match('/[^ A-Za-z 0-9 ,.-()]/'), $edit-pass-pass1
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't re-invent the wheel if these will solve your needs and hopefully wants.

https://www.drupal.org/project/password_policy

also worth looking into
https://www.drupal.org/project/password_strength

If those don't work, I think you're looking at a form alter related to validation. Drupal 8 is the wonderful world of Form Alters... so look into those even if the above solves your needs.

Comment: you are right using this modules i can solve this issues but i would not like to use these modules. How could i alter filed validation for core modules  my requirement is allow in password filed `A-Za-z 0-9 ,.-()`please guide me

Comment: i have try this modules but password encryption is not working, so i'm thinking i could alter only password field

Answer (score 0):

Read you comments on my other answer. Here's how I would start tackling in your situation. I think you're going down a Form Alter method.  Start off simple.  Create a new module with just an .info and .module.  In the .module, add code to find what you're looking for. KSM will show you the array and you can dig in.

```
/**
 * Implements form_alter().
 * form_id : node_check_in_form 
 */
function yourmodulename_form_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  ksm($form_id);
  switch ($form_id) {
    //turn off the ability to edit 'type' after creation per spec
    case 'yourcasehere':
      ksm($form);
      break;
...
```

Basically, figure out your form name. Then see what the form is. You can alter the form to have new validation.

https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/entity-api/entity-validation-api/providing-a-custom-validation-constraint